# How to get the number of login of the user in the app in a day?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have this app build in flutter with Firebase and I wanted to know if I can get the total number of login the user have in a day? Is that possible?

Comment: you can write that logic locally, can maintain that count in sharedPref

Answer (score 1):

Enable Firebase analytics in the console.
Import the firebase analytics package in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.14
```

The number of logins, register and active user will be uploaded automatically to the console.